# 'Error converting datatype of varchar to real' in SSRS but query runs all okay in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a query that I use in a SSRS report.
I tried to add some columns to this but the query doesn't run/build and returns the error that is in the title.
However, the same query runs 100% okay in SSMS and only fails when transferred into SSRS.

This is the query, I have had to redact some columns and table names as per my company policy

```
select x.* ,
dbo.wc_calculateRateDecimal([Num Accepted],[Num Of Students]) as 'Percentage Usage'
from
(SELECT mainSct_id,
       Count(stu_id) AS 'Num Of Students',
       Sum(CASE
      WHEN COALESCE(eng.[Ts And Cs Accepted], 'No') = 'Yes' THEN 1
     ELSE 0
   END  )    AS 'Num Accepted',
    sum(eng.[Connection Requests]) as [Connection Requests],
    sum(eng.[Direct Messages])as[Direct Messages],
    sum(eng.[Group Posts])as [Group Posts],
    sum(eng.[Profile Posts])as [Profile Posts]
FROM   REDACTED stu
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (select * from REDACTED  where [Ts And Cs Accepted] ='Yes')eng 
                    ON stu.REDACTED = eng.REDACTED
                       AND stu.REDACTED = eng.REDACTED
WHERE  acy_id = '21/22'
       AND mainCrs_catType != 'APP'
       AND mainCrsProgress_id IN ( 'A', 'C', 'F' )
       AND mainCrs_catType = 'POS'
```

The columns inside the SUMS are all floats. I have tried casting these to `varchar` and to `real` but with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: what type does dbo.wc_calculateRateDecimal return?

Comment: FYI, the query you have provided isn't complete. You don't close the parentheses on one of your derived tables, nor alias it.

Comment: And are there any SSRS parameters?

Comment: Side note, don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They only work when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'value'` would *not* order by a column aliased as `'value'`, it would order by the `varchar` literal `'value'` (so would effectively not order at all). Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: Is it correct that the "previous" version of the query worked correctly with SSRS? If so, either identify exactly what you changed or add the previous version to your question. Did you remove the report parameters by replacing them with constants to make it runnable in SSMS?

Comment: @SMor the only changes were the addition of 
`sum(eng.[Connection Requests]) as [Connection Requests],
 sum(eng.[Direct Messages])as[Direct Messages],
 sum(eng.[Group Posts])as [Group Posts],
 sum(eng.[Profile Posts])as [Profile Posts]`.


And yes in SSMS i manually set the values that use parameters to a value from the list in SSRS exactly how it would be

Answer (score -1):

Assuming there are no parameters being passed that could cause an issue, I would guess it's the session options that differ between SSMS and SSRS.

You can use this to determine the current settings from SSMS

```
DECLARE @options INT SELECT @options = @@OPTIONS 
PRINT @options
IF ( (1 & @options) = 1 ) PRINT 'DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK' 
IF ( (2 & @options) = 2 ) PRINT 'IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS' 
IF ( (4 & @options) = 4 ) PRINT 'CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT' 
IF ( (8 & @options) = 8 ) PRINT 'ANSI_WARNINGS' 
IF ( (16 & @options) = 16 ) PRINT 'ANSI_PADDING' 
IF ( (32 & @options) = 32 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS' 
IF ( (64 & @options) = 64 ) PRINT 'ARITHABORT' 
IF ( (128 & @options) = 128 ) PRINT 'ARITHIGNORE'
IF ( (256 & @options) = 256 ) PRINT 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' 
IF ( (512 & @options) = 512 ) PRINT 'NOCOUNT' 
IF ( (1024 & @options) = 1024 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON' 
IF ( (2048 & @options) = 2048 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF' 
IF ( (4096 & @options) = 4096 ) PRINT 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL' 
IF ( (8192 & @options) = 8192 ) PRINT 'NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT' 
IF ( (16384 & @options) = 16384 ) PRINT 'XACT_ABORT'
```

Then you can replicate these at the start of your dataset query making sure that those that are not listed in the query above are explicitly set.